# Decomposing residuals into between and within group in Pymer4

Tags: python, statsmodels, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

i have a question about mixed-effect in Pymer4 (same of lme4 but in python). My model is fitted under machine-learning to get the predicted values (Observed_values = predicted_values + total_residuals)
and I want to split my residuals into between-group and within group using random-effect maximum likelihood estimation in Pymer4

and how to define the between and within-group residuals ?

Where the between-group residuals are determined as the average deviation of observed values from median predictions for a given group.

While the within-group residuals are a measure of misfit between an individual observation at a record and the group-specific median prediction.
in summary total_residuals = between_group + within_group

So the start of code is like this way?

```
from pymer4.models import Lmer

model = Lmer('observed_target_values ~ predicted_target_values + (1|group_id) ', data=df)

model.fit()
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to mean-centre the variables within groups/subjects/IDs and include the group means as level-2 predictors. So you would create new variables for the mean of each variable within each group and then subtract this from the individual level values, and then also include the mean of each group in the model along with the offseted variables.

The estimates for the centred variables will be within-subject and the estimates for the means will be between.